# Wordpress - Disable Search Function

Tags: wordpress, search

I've added the following code to functions.php to disable archived/crawled/url searching on my wordpress site for performance reasons:

```
function disable_search( $query, $error = true ) {
  if ( is_search() ) {
$query->is_search = false;
$query->query_vars[s] = false;
$query->query[s] = false;
// to error
if ( $error == true )
$query->is_404 = true;
  }
}

add_action( 'parse_query', 'disable_search' );
add_filter( 'get_search_form', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```

This works perfectly to prevent searching, but also prevents searching for posts in the admin area.

Is there a way to disable searches for users but still allow the admins to search?

Currently, my workaround is to remove this code, perform my necessary search, then paste it back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try `is_admin` function? It will **return true** if the Dashboard or the administration panel is attempting to be displayed. So put this function to your code, it will not fire in Dashboard:

```
function disable_search($query, $error = true)
{
    if (is_search() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->is_search = false;
        $query->query_vars[s] = false;
        $query->query[s] = false;

        // to error

        if ($error == true) $query->is_404 = true;
    }
}

add_action('parse_query', 'disable_search');
add_filter('get_search_form', function(){ return null; });
```

Or:

```
function disable_search($query, $error = true)
{
    if (is_search()) {
        $query->is_search = false;
        $query->query_vars[s] = false;
        $query->query[s] = false;

        // to error

        if ($error == true) $query->is_404 = true;
    }
}

if(!is_admin()){
    add_action('parse_query', 'disable_search');
    add_filter('get_search_form', function(){ return null; });
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out that you need a 404.php page in your theme or this code (or from any other replies) won't work.

Comment: In `[s]`, `s` should be quoted. Instead of `function(){ return null; }`, `'__return_null'` could be used for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

create_function is deprecated for PHP 7.2+

This seem to work (to put in your function.php) :

```
function fb_filter_query( $query, $error = true ) {

    if ( is_search() ) {
        $query->is_search = false;
        $query->query_vars['s'] = false;
        $query->query['s'] = false;

        if ( $error == true )
            $query->is_404 = true;
    }
}

add_action( 'parse_query', 'fb_filter_query' );
add_filter( 'get_search_form', function() { return null;} );
```